# User Login with Read Access and Create/Alter View Access in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, authentication, database-administration

I need to create a user login

- who has read access to tables/views
- who has create/alter view access
- who does not have create/alter table access

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to make them a member of the [db_datareader] role, so the can SELECT any data from tables/views.

Then, you will need to create them a new schema to create their views in. Unfortunately, CREATE VIEW and ALTER VIEW also require ALTER SCHEMA permission, which is rather high privilege, and can allow the user to alter tables or even drop them.

So, rather than grant them ALTER SCHEMA on the [dbo] schema (where I assume your tables are), create them their own schema and let them go nuts in there. Also, DENY them alter permission on the [dbo] schema so they cannot inadvertently do bad things...

The code (SQL 2012) is:

```
-- add Login_Name to the [db_datareader] role
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [Login_Name]; 
go

-- Now create them a Schema
create schema [UserViews];

-- Now, grant the user alter table, alter view, create table, create view and alter schema on the schema
GRANT ALTER on SCHEMA::[UserViews] to [Login_Name]
go
-- Deny alter on the dbo schema
DENY ALTER on SCHEMA::[dbo] to [Login_Name]
go
-- Now let them create tables (but only in the UserViews schema)
GRANT CREATE TABLE to [Login_Name]
go
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. But if he should have alter view access on dbo schema to modify existing views ?  Also I found something while searching "GRANT ALTER VIEW TO User. But it doesn't work as expected. Any thoughts on what this command does.

Answer (score 0):

As of SQL 2016 and higher, I believe "db_datareader" (for whichever DB they need to create views for) plus "create view" access gives them what they need? Also, I believe "create view" also implies "alter view" - at least for any views you create yourself - i.e., when you create a view you are, in effect, the owner. - ? Also, no need to separately grant "create table," if I recall correctly. And, finally, no need to "deny alter on dbo schema," if you're explicitly granting Alter to only the "UserViews" schema.